# Webcam Stream With ffmpeg: UDP Stream remotely

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I've a C920 HD camera connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 and my goal is to be able to access a stream of that camera anytime from my phone / laptop both connected to my network with a VPN.

Now, I managed to use ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 \
-video_size 1920x1080 \
-i /dev/video4 \
-copyinkf -codec copy \
-f mpegts udp://192.168.1.10:5000?pkt_size=1316
```

On the computer `192.168.1.10` I can launch VLC go into "Network Transmission" and type `udp://@:5000` in oder to watch the stream.

This is a single stream and from what I understand my RPi is just "shooting" the frames at that computer whatever it is connected or not, how can I have a proper stream (maybe rtmp?) that I can watch in multiple devices?

Please note: I'm using `-copyinkf -codec copy` in order to avoid transcoding and other operations that might result in a very high CPU usage. Can I do it this way also?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx can be configured to host an RTMP video stream that will be used to play the stream coming from `ffmpeg` in all my devices. For this we need to install `libnginx-mod-rtmp` and configure nginx for RTMP:

1. `apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp`
2. Append the following to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;
                allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                deny publish all;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

3. `systemctl restart nginx`
4. Point `ffmpeg` to the nginx server:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 \
-video_size 1920x1080 \
-i /dev/video4 \
-copyinkf -codec copy \
-f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/stream
```

I also changed the output format to `flv` in order to improve compatibility with players.

Enjoy.